# Where do I file bugs for Jupiter applet?

Tags: unity, bug-reporting, jupiter

I've downloaded the Juputer power management tool via PPA, and I want to file a bug for it regarding its integration with the unity-panel. Where do I file this? There doesn't appear to be a page under www.bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jupiter.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the WebUpd8 team is responsible for the PPA for the Jupiter applet on Launchpad since the Official Jupiter applet page on Launchpad seems to be inactive. Their bug tracker uses sourceforge and seems to be curently disabled.

So your only viable option would be to register the bugs with the WebUpd8 team on Launchpad. They say on their Launchpad page to contact them with bugs if any on [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~webupd8team) page

All related links:

- [WebUpd8's Jupiter Applet on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter)
- [WebUpd8's Bugs Page on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~webupd8team)
- [Jupiter Applet's Lauchpad page](https://launchpad.net/jupiter-project)
- [Jupiter Applet's Bug Inactive Bug Tracker on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=add&group_id=280277&atid=1189425)
- [Jupiter Applet's Support Page *(Note: The link under
  Ubuntu->Launchpad will take you to the WebUpd8 team's page for
  Jupiter Applet)*](http://www.jupiterapplet.org/support.html)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, but the WebUp8 Launchpad page doesn't allow you to file bugs. It only allows you to view bugs, but it seems there haven't been any bugs filed at all.

Comment: Try contacting the WebUpd8 team maybe?

Comment: you file all bugs on launchpad.